# Normality tests of distribution and autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation, independence, normality-assumption

I have a sample of observation on which normality tests (Anderson Darling, Shapiro - Wilks, KS,...) would accept the assumption of normality. Nevertheless I know that there is a certain time - dependence (autocorrelation) of subsequent observations. I would like to know if I can state the normality of distribution regardless partial dependency of subsequent observations (any reference would be greatly accepted).

Comment: You never accept a null hypothesis, you just have insufficient data to reject the hypthesis that your variables are not normal. An absence of evidence is not the same as evidence of absence.

Comment: Could you perhaps 'thin' your observations (ie take one every N observations, N=2 to 10 depending on degree of autocorrelation) to remove autocorrelation? Then if your analyses don't give markedly different results perhaps reduce the thinning to improve precision.

Comment: Also is there any reason not to model this as a time series?